# Grails Spock testing for a specific exception

Tags: grails, groovy, exception, spock

I'm working with Grails 2.4.5 and struggling to get Grails to delineate different exception types.

Suppose I want to mock the below:

```
class FooController { 
def barService
...
def fooAction() {
try {
barService.someMethod(params)
} catch(e) {
if (e instanceof FooException) { ... }
else if (e instanceof BarException) { ... }
else { ... }
}
}
```

Given the test below

```
    @TestFor(FooController)
    class FooControllerSpec extends Specification {
    def setup() { controller.barService = Mock(BarService) }
    void "test"() {
      given: "a mock dependency"
      1* controller.barService.someMethod(_) >> { -> throw FooException('foo') }

      when: "the action is requested"
      controller.fooAction()

      then: "expect the FooException behaviour from the action"
      // some behaviour
    }
```

I would expect the FooException within the mock dependency closure to have thrown

however, debugging shows the below instead:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: somePackage.FooControllerSpec$_$spock_feature_0_9_closure14.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.Arrays$ArrayList) values: [[[:]]]
```

Is this a bug? is there a way to mock different Exceptions in the fashion described above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify behaviour in the `then` block, ie:

```
void "test"() {
  when: "the action is requested"
  controller.fooAction()

  then: "expect the FooException behaviour from the action"
  1 * controller.barService.someMethod(_) >> { -> throw new FooException('foo') }
  response.redirectedUrl == "/some/other/path"
}
```

Comment: the thing is, the exceptions in the implementation are handled within the action.  The controller isn't bubbling them up by design.  had the `catch(e)`  gone to `throw e` you could test if the action had thrown the exception.  Unfortunately that option isn't available here.

Comment: What does it do in the case of a FooException?

Comment: Typically, something like a redirect to a logout.

Comment: instead of `thrown`, can you do `response.redirectedUrl == "/some/other/path"`?

Comment: That won't work because the exception type _isn't_ the `FooException`, it's `MissingMethodException`

Comment: I'm confused and lost now :-(

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: So the issue is that the unit test is not throwing a FooException.  Something under the hood in Grails/Spock-for-Grails is not handling the closure `{ -> throw FooException('foo') }` properly.  When the action is called by spock, the action is calling the mocked service method but is subsequently throwing a `MissingMethodException`

Comment: Syntax doesn't work for me, try, 1* controller.barService.someMethod(_) >> { throw new FooException('foo') }

Comment: Ah! :) I could have sworn blind I tried that before and it didn't work, but - yes - that's working for me now! thanks!

Comment: As an aside, since this may catch others out, I've noticed a second issue that conflated with this issue and probably caused me some confusion in the process.  One of the exceptions I'm testing is a validation exception.  when I tested it, it had been throwing a MissingMethodException one way and a NullPointerException the other.  ValidationExceptions, I have discovered, should be mocked as: `new ValidationException('message', new GrailsMockErrors(new FooDomainClass())`